# Activity lifecycle onStop() not called immediately when Activity goes into onPause() lifecycle

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have the following scenario with a PlayerActivity.

When I press the back button on the Player (while it's playing), the PlayerActivity calls the `onPause()`, then `onStop()` and finally `onDestroy()` as expected.

However, when I cause the PlayerActivity to go into the paused state (such as initiate a Voice search) and then allow it to go into the resumed state (by exiting the voice search), and then press the back button the Activity's `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` methods are not called - only `onPause()` is called.

So my question is this - is there a reason why `onStop()` isn't called even though the Activity is no longer visible?

These are the logs to help visualise this scenario:

```
Normal activity lifecycle for player:
01-10 18:44:58.799 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onCreate()
01-10 18:44:58.916 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onStart()
01-10 18:44:58.917 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onResume()
Back button pressed on PlayerActivity:
01-10 18:45:14.768 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onPause()
01-10 18:45:14.968 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onStop()
01-10 18:45:14.968 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onDestroy()
PlayerActivity destroyed.

Player initiated second time:
01-10 18:45:21.874 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onCreate()
01-10 18:45:21.899 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onStart()
01-10 18:45:21.899 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onResume()
Voice control is initiated on TV remote - causes Activity to PAUSE state
01-10 18:45:27.180 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onPause()
Voice control finished causing Activity to RESUMED state
01-10 18:45:29.414 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onResume()
Back button pressed on PlayerActivity
01-10 18:45:32.160 27817-27817/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo D/PlayerActivity: onPause()
// This is it - Activity’s onStop() and onDestroy() not called
```

Comment: How are you calling the activity for the voice control? Are you "finishing" that activity or is it still lingering on the stack?

Comment: Hi, I've overridden the onBackPressed to finish() the Activity but still same result